# Why am I getting a 'Value!' error in my VBA function for calculating logarithmic averages?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, range, acoustics

I'm getting a #Value! error with this.
The udf I am creating should return the log average of the 8 cells to the left of the cell in which you type the function.
I think the error has to do with how I'm selecting the range over which to loop. Would this work in a udf?

```
    Set rngValues = Range.FormulaR1C1 = "(RC[-8]:RC[-1])"
```

I've used R1C1 to call the cells I am operating over but am unsure whether this is the best way to do it. Any helpful suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What are you passing to the function? Just pass those 8 cells. Then you can omit the critical row - which doesn't work at all.

Comment: Thanks Ike. How would you pass those 8 cells to the function?

Comment: just like you would do it for a normal Excel function ...

Comment: I don't understand. Could you specify please?

Comment: `Set rngValues = Range.FormulaR1C1 = "(RC[-8]:RC[-1])"` is not selecting a range nor does it compile.
Put something like this in your formula `=dbax(A2:H2)` - when you drag it down (or across) the references will automatically change

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Thanks CHill60, and Ike for the tip. The issue is the function needs to be blank in the parentheses ("=dbax()") to work in the sheets I am implementing it in. So I'm looking to have the code always take the 8 cells to the left of the active cell in which I write =dbax(). Does that make sense? Apologies if it's an obvious one but I'm new at VBA.

Answer (score 1):

a) You use a UDF (User Defined Function) like any function that is part of Excel: If you want to calculate the sum of some cells, you write the formula `=Sum(A1:A10)`. You can do exactly the same for an own function: Just write `=dbax(A1:A10)` (adapt to the Range that you really want to use). Excel will pass the Range A1:A10 to the function.
As written in the comments: Remove the `Set rngValues = ...` line. `rngValues` is set already, plus the syntax of the statement is invalid.

b) Assuming that your data is okay (all cells contain numeric values), the function should work. However, you are not returning the calculated result: When your function name is `dbax`, the last statement should be

```
dbax = 10 * .Log10(lSumofValues / lCountofValues)
```

Comment: Thank you FunThomas. That's really helpful (i'm new to VBA).
I've updated the last line accordingly. 

My mine issue is I am using this function in a separate sheet where it needs to remain blank in the parentheses ("=dbax()") to work across the sheet. So I'm looking for it to automatically calculate within the 8 cells to the left of the active cell in which it's written. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: An UDF never should use the Active cell. What is the `Active Cell` - you can never tell because it is not in your hands when Excel decides to re-calculate the sheet. If you mean with *active cell* the cell where the formula lives in: You can use the solution @Ike provided, but I don't see the point in why you don't want to pass the range as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pass the range to calculate on then you have to use `Application.Caller` which returns the cell range of the formula:

```vb
Dim rngFunction As Range
Set rngFunction = Application.Caller
        
Dim rngValues As Range
Set rngValues = rngFunction.Offset(, -8).Resize(, 8)
```

Remove parameter `rngValues as Range`!

**Caveat of this solution**: if you change any of the 8 values there **the formula won't be re-calculated!**.

To me it is not clear why you can't pass the range as parameter like this `=dbax(A2:H2)`. Then the formula would re-calculate if you change any of the values.

Comment: Thanks Ike! This is getting there! The next question is of course is there a way of not passing the range to calculate that will allow the formula to recalculate when changing any of the 8 values? I'm looking at doing it without looping.. as follows:
Function dbax2() As Double
    dbax2 = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=10*LOG((10^(RC[-8]/10)+10^(RC[-7]/10)+10^(RC[-6]/10)+10^(RC[-5]/10)+10^(RC[-4]/10)+10^(RC[-3]/10)+10^(RC[-2]/10)+10^(RC[-1]/10))/8)"
End Function

This doesn't seem to work though.. any obvious issues there? I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Please clarify - within your question - what you want to achieve. And why you can't pass the range to the UDF. To me it is absolutly not clear what you want to achieve with `dbax2 = activecell.formular1c1 = "= ..."`. This will return true or false depending on the formula of the active cell.